# Initialize an std::vector from members of another vector using modern C++

Tags: c++

Is there a nicer way in modern C++ to initialize a vector from members of another vector? E.g. using lambdas?

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

struct IntRectangle {
  uint64_t id;
  std::array<uint64_t, 2> width_height;
};

std::vector<std::array<uint64_t, 2>> rect2array(const std::vector<IntRectangle>& rects) {
  std::vector<std::array<uint64_t, 2>> rect_array;
  rect_array.reserve(rects.size());
  for (const auto& rect : rects) {
    rect_array.push_back(std::array<uint64_t, 2>{ rect.width_height });
  }

  return rect_array;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply using `std::copy()`?

Comment: It seems like you want to *transform* one kind of vector into another kind of vector. For that the [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) function would be suitable.

Comment: If you do not want to copy the data and just have a "reference" to it, you could use ranges and a `transform_view` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `transform`

```cpp
std::vector<std::array<uint64_t, 2>> rect2array(const std::vector<IntRectangle>& rects) {
  std::vector<std::array<uint64_t, 2>> rect_array;
  rect_array.reserve(rects.size());
  std::transform(std::begin(rects), std::end(rects), std::back_inserter(rect_array), [](const auto& ir) {
      return ir.width_height;
  });

  return rect_array;
}
```

[Demo online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1T3hnWzeY)

I think it's not necessary to copy the `width_height` when the array have large size and the argument's life-time is long enough, then we may return a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::array<uint64_t, 2>>>`

Comment: Quite a few of those `std::` qualifications are unnecessary. `std::begin(rects)` can be `begin(rects)` because `rects` is a `std::vector` so Argument-Dependent Lookup kicks in. You can also make it less verbose by declaring the return type as `auto`.

Comment: Thanks @prehistoricpenguin, that is a nice way to write it. Since the my question got (correctly) flagged as being similar to another one, I delayed my response a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
rect_array.reserve(rects.size());    
std::transform(rects.cbegin(), rects.cend(), std::back_inserter(rect_array), [](const auto& rect) {
    return rect.width_height;
});
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: @Zoso What is the difference between the for range loop in the question and std::transform in your answer?